# Execute Javascript function on set date in the future

Tags: javascript

Is it possibble to execute a function in JS at a set date and time in the future?

I have a `<h3>` of which I want to change the `class` on April 10 at 12:00. Is this possible and if so, could someone please point me in the right direction? Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, this possible, but what did you try? Where’s your own best attempt? What went wrong, in what way? What specific help do you need? Please: read the guidelines on both “*[ask]*” and “*[mcve]*”, then [edit] your question.

Comment: Hi David, you're riight, and I asked too soon. I managed to sort it out. If you have any comments on improvement to my solution, I would be happy to hear them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function () {
      var date = new Date();
      if (date.getMonth() === 6 && date.getDate() === 10 && date.getHours() === 15 && date.getMinutes() === 00) {
          document.getElementById('h3-date').innerHTML = "New text";
      }
  }, 1000)
```